# Chinese Localization during PDF Generation on a Chinese server results in blocks being printed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

We have an ASP.Net MVC application that we are localizing to multiple languages. All languages are rendered right on the UI, including Chinese. When generating a pdf, using ExpertPDF, the Chinese PDF is fine as long as the OS acting as the server is not in Chinese (We've tried English, French, Dutch, Polish, Spanish, German). However, upon changing the OS localization (winsystemlocale) to zh-CN, the PDF generation somehow breaks. BUT, only the PDF generation breaks, the UI is rendered just fine.

We don't do anything special to the actual content of the generated PDF when we process it with ExpertPDF, we literally just pass the html of the existing screen with some layout changes.

We've been scratching our heads with this one. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**
Upon downloading both the broken pdf and a correct pdf, we found out that somehow the embedded fonts change depending on the winsystemlocale. It seems that the library can't find the SimSun font when the winsystemlocale is in zh-CN.

Further investigation also suggests that for some reason, .NET can no longer supply the correct fallback font to the PDF once the winsystemlocale is in zh-CN. We're aware that the display name for SimSun font changes but can still be initialize using the same text.

Here is the code we use to generate the PDF

```
docTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(docTitle) ? "DXT Document" : docTitle;
            byte[] pdfBytes = null;
            PdfConverter converter = CreateConverter();
            converter.PdfDocumentInfo.Title = docTitle;
            HtmlToPdfArea header = new HtmlToPdfArea(headerHtml, baseURL);
            HtmlToPdfArea footer = new HtmlToPdfArea(footerHtml, baseURL);
            header.AddPadding = true;
            footer.AddPadding = true;
            header.FitHeight = true;
            header.FitWidth = true;
            footer.FitHeight = true;
            footer.FitWidth = true;
            converter.PdfHeaderOptions.AddHtmlToPdfArea(header);
            converter.PdfFooterOptions.AddHtmlToPdfArea(footer);
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = isLandscape ? PDFPageOrientation.Landscape : PDFPageOrientation.Portrait;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.FitWidth = true;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.EmbedFonts = true;
            converter.PageWidth = virtualViewWidth;
            converter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderHeight = headerHeight;
            var translated = LocalizationService.GetTranslation<Resources.Apheresis.ProcedureRecords>("Of");
            converter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea = new TextArea(pageNumberXPos, pageNumberYPos, $"&p; {translated} &P;",
                new System.Drawing.Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Arial"), 8, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point));
            Document doc = converter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlString(contentHtml, baseURL);
            doc.OpenAction.Action = new ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf.PdfDocument.PdfActionJavaScript("print();");
            pdfBytes = doc.Save();
```

Here is the screen
[image]

Here is the generated PDF
[image]

Comment: This looks a lot like an encoding/ decoding error. Are you specifying the character encoding anywhere? Else I cannot say much more without an [mcve] code sample to reproduce the problem and try and fix it

Comment: Also (somewhat) obligatory [XKCD](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/encoding.png)

Comment: My guess would be a font problem. But that's all pretty blind guessing as long as you don't show us the code how you are generating this pdf.

Comment: Hello everyone, I just downloaded the generated PDFs and it does seem like the font SimSun is not being embedded. However, we don't explicitly embed any fonts. I'll be updating with the code in a few

Comment: My guess: you "pull" the PDF content from `contentHtml`, right? Windows uses a standard Chinese font like SimSun as "fallback"; i.e. when you have text in Arial with Chinese characters in between, Windows will automatically switch to SimSun to display these. => Works in a standard UI. If the Chinese characters in your HTML content do not have an explicit style with font set to SimSun, the PDF renderer won't be aware of that "fallback" fix and will try to render them in standard Latin font. Also "*we don't explicitly embed any fonts*" : `converter.PdfDocumentOptions.EmbedFonts = true;` ;-)

Comment: Hi LocEngineer, I meant we don't list out the fonts to embed. and yes, you're correct that the contentHtml is the content we're running through the library. An observation I noticed is that on a different winsystemlocale, .Net is able to "fallback" and use SimSun for chinese characters. It's only when the winsystemlocale is set to chinese that it breaks. During debug, I changed my machine's locale to chinese and saw that the font SimSun is no longer identified like "SimSun" and now uses Chinese characters. I don't know if there is a key I can use that won't get translated